# Some matrix help

Tags: matrices

I have been trying for a while with the use of previous questions without luck.

Making the matrix itself is no problem,

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        k_0 \times k \\
        k_1 \times k \\
        k_2 \times k \\
        \vdots \\
        k_N \times k \\
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
```

But I want to have a curly bracket on the left side of the matrix indicating that the sum of k's = k like this:

```
k{
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but perhaps `k\left\{\begin{pmatrix...\end{pmatrix}\right.` ?

Comment: Well that was simple, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\[ k\left\{\begin{pmatrix} ...\end{pmatrix}\right. \]
```

To get a brace to the left of the matrix